# Modify opened file and save it

Tags: delphi, header, endianness, lzma

My program works with some files that are stored in a 7z/ZIP file. However some of the 7z/ZIP files have modified headers so it is necessary to change them to valid ones before extracting.

Modified headers are always the same so it is contained in a const variable (along with valid one):

```
to_fix := 1629246124;
PKZip := 1347093252;
```

Replacement solution is quite easy and I hope I've done it in right way:

```
for i := 0 to filesize(F) do
begin
  if i < filesize(F) - 3 then
  BlockRead(F, buf, 4);
  if buf = to_fix then
  begin
    Seek(F, i);
    BlockWrite(F, PKZip, 4);
  end;
  buf := 0;
  Seek(F, i+1);
end;
```

The problem I get is whenever I replace all the instances of `to_fix` with `PKZip` in little- or big-endian order, I always get the same order being written to the file: `04 03 4b 50` instead of `50 4b 03 04`.

I tried the following:

```
const PKZip_B1: array[0..3] of byte = (4,3,75,80);
const PKZip_B2: array[0..3] of byte = (80,75,3,4);

const PKZip_I1 = 67324752;   //04 03 4b 50   to decimal
const PKZip_I2 = 1347093252; //50 4b 03 04   to decimal
```

All of the above variants replace in wrong order.

Why is this happening? I am using Delphi 7 on 64-bit processor (I bet the issue is due to this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both x86 and x64 processors are little endian. That is not your issue.

Let's assume that you are writing `1347093252` as a 32 bit integer, which in hex is `$504b0304`. Your machine is little endian and so the bytes are writen in reverse order.

Instead if you write `$04034b50`, then the bytes will be written `$50` first and so on.

However, if you really want to write out 4 bytes in a particular order, do just that. For instance instead of writing `$04034b50` as a little endian 32 bit integer, write:

```
const 
  Header: array [0..3] of Byte = ($50, $4b, $03, $04);
```

This is the cleanest approach.

There's obviously a degree of confusion here. Stop treating the values as integers and instead consider them as arrays of bytes. That removes endianness from the picture. Then work out which 4 bytes you need to write, put them in an array, and write them.

Clearly you'd need to apply the same approach to data read from the file. Read it into an array and compare the individual bytes. Or, read it into an integer and use `CompareMem` to compare against an array.

Finally, I don't see any evidence that you are definitely finding the right 4 header bytes. Perhaps you are modifying the data also, and so corrupting the file. It's not at all clear to me that you've diagnosed the problem correctly. I suggest that you ensure that you have an accurate diagnosis before implementing a solution. Once you have that diagnosis then you might look for a solution that avoids writing the wrong header value in the first place. Attack the problem at source.

Comment: And `67324752` in hex is `04034b50` :/ I tried all of the possible ways. I tried the one you suggested as well as reversed one (`$504b0304`) and i always get wrong order written! As to your edits, if i do `BlockWrite(F, Header, 4)` i still get wrong order. I tried to put `BlockWrite` in a 4-iteration loopbut it still didnt work. I still dont get why reversed and valid values are written in same order...

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the way i search the occurance of modified headers?

Comment: Re first comment, that can't happen. When you write an array of byte, the bytes are written in array order. I suggest that you need to step back and work out what is really going on. I trust you are debugging with a hex editor?

Comment: Re second comment, it's plausible that you are not writing where you think you are writing. Personally I'd opt for a stream here but that shouldn't really be the issue. You do need to identify the problem. At least you now know how to write bytes and be sure of their order.

Comment: I've expanded my answer somewhat. I think you need to step back and make sure you clearly understand your problem. It seems likely that you don't yet. At the moment you seem to be grasping for silver bullets. My instincts tell me that will not be productive.

Comment: I get you, indeed. Doing tests in my case are a bit time consuming. And i've figured out what was the problem: my misunderstaning of how does `BlockWrite` works with files being opened by `Reset`. Program modified source file and didnt replace all the instances since 0 of the, occured.